# Issues importing 3d model into ThreeJS

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, 3d, gltf

I'm brand new to ThreeJS and I'm learning how to import 3D models.

I'm trying to import a [3D car model](https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/ford-mustang-1965-5f4e3965f79540a9888b5d05acea5943) from **Sketchfab** into **ThreeJS** using **GLTFLoader**.

When I run the page I get a grey canvas with nothing in it, and the console errors:

```
256 >[.WebGL-0x12400b72300] GL_INVALID_OPERATION: Feedback loop formed between Framebuffer and active Texture.

WebGL: too many errors, no more errors will be reported to the console for this context.
```

I've been trying to fix this error but I wasn't been able to. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I've tried the following code with `scene.gltf` is in the directory along with the `index.html` and `main.js` files.

#### index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>3D-Mustang -- Nathan Kenopic</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <canvas class="webgl"></canvas>

    <script type="module" src="./main.js"></script>
</body>
<footer>
    <h3>3D Model made by Pooya_dh https://sketchfab.com/Pooya_dh</h3>
</footer>
</html>
```

#### main.js

```js
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls'
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader'

const scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xdddddd);

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(40, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 5000);
camera.rotation.y = 45 / 180 * Math.PI;
camera.position.x = 800;
camera.position.y = 100;
camera.position.z = 1000;

scene.add(camera);

const canvas = document.querySelector('.webgl');

const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, canvas);
controls.enableDamping = true;
controls.enablePan = false;
controls.enableZoom = false;
controls.autoRotate = true;
controls.autoRotateSpeed = 10;


const hlight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040, 100);
scene.add(hlight);


const directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 100);
directionalLight.position.set(0, 1, 0);
directionalLight.castShadow = true;

scene.add(directionalLight);


const light = new THREE.PointLight(0xc4c4c4, 10);
light.position.set(0, 300, 500);
scene.add(light);

const light2 = new THREE.PointLight(0xc4c4c4, 10);
light2.position.set(500, 100, 0);
scene.add(light2);

const light3 = new THREE.PointLight(0xc4c4c4, 10);
light3.position.set(0, 100, -500);
scene.add(light3);

const light4 = new THREE.PointLight(0xc4c4c4, 10);
light4.position.set(-500, 300, 500);
scene.add(light4);


const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas});
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);


const loader = new GLTFLoader();
loader.load('scene.gltf', function (gltf) {
    let car = gltf.scene.children[0];
    car.scale.set(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);

    let model = gltf.scene;
    scene.add(model);
});

function animate() {
    controls.update();
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
animate();
```

Comment: The lines ` let car = gltf.scene.children[0]` and `car.scale.set(0.5, 0.5, 0.5)` are not really needed since you add this to the scene: `let model = gltf.scene`. Try scaling the `model`, `model.scale.set(0.1, 0.1, 0.1)` or  `model.scale.set(10, 10, 10)`. Maybe the model is large or small.

Comment: Haha thank you so much! turns out it was that scaling issue. I didn't realize the scale difference, so changing it to model.scale.set(10,10,10) worked perfectly!